# Select an array of subdocuments and include fields from the parent in each

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have a document like this:

```
{
    _id: "a",
    title: "Hello",
    info: [
       {
           _id: "a1",
           item: "b"
       },
       {
           _id: "a2",
           item: "c"
       },
    ]
}
```

I want to query this document so that I get a result like:

```
[
    {
        title: "Hello",
        _id: "a1",
        item: "b"
    },
    {
        title: "Hello",
        _id: "a2",
        item: "c"
    }
]
```

If I only want to get a single one of those items, say the item where

```
_id: "a1"
```

I can do a query like

```
findOne ( { "info._id": "a1" }, { title: 1, "info._id": 1, "info.item": 1, _id: 0 } );
```

I will get the correct result for a single sub-document. My question is how do I expand this to work for *each* item?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation framework's **$unwind** operator to transform your one element with nested array to two documents with nested info field. Then you can use **$project** to get rid of nesting. In last stage you can filter new form using **$match**.

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([
   { $unwind: "$info" },
   { $project: { title: 1, _id: "$info._id", item: "$info.item"} },
   { $match: {_id: "a1"}}
])
```

Such query will return one document like this:

```
{ "title" : "Hello", "_id" : "a1", "item" : "b" }
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB aggregate operation facilitates applying filter into embedded documents using combination of  [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)  and [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) aggregation stages.

According to description as mentioned into above question please try executing following aggregate query into MongoDB shell.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                "_id": "a"
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$info",

                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $match: {
                'info._id': 'a1'
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $project: {
                title: 1,
                _id: '$info._id',
                item: '$info.item'
            }
        },

    ]



);
```